# Android Widget ImageView not show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I just start a widget and its xml show the imageview in the emulator on AS, but whatever i put the imageview at what position the image is not show. Here is my xml layout of widget

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#333"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="16:00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="14:00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: emulator]

[image: on test phone]

Even I put inside the linearlayout or relativelayout with hard code dp or other options and even change with other project picture which is ok inside the app, nothing showed. I just wonder what is the reason of it not show.

Answer (score 10):

I found one more option. You can set background of the ImageView to show your drawable instead of setting 'src'. Again, still not very good solution, however drawable is visible.

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Comment: What I did to make it work is to use a `FrameLayout` and `android:background` property instead of `ImageView`. Same thing I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Try using android:src instead of app:srcCompat. I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works for me.

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. I tried to change all imageview with src , but still not work in the widget. I find this is work on the activity, but change to widget, it is still  blank

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_media_next"
```

instead of

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` will be drawn above the `ImageView` so it is not visible.

Try to set `LinearLayout` below `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" //add this to set this layout below imageview
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="10">
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I tried this way, it still have not render anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the image wasn't shown on the widget when image's drawable contained a theme-dependent color, for example:

```css
android:fillColor="?attr/themeColorBase80"
```

Check, maybe your drawables drawable/ic_popup_sync and drawable/ic_media_next contain any attributes defined implicitly, with other attributes.

If so, use explicitly defined attributes, for example:

```css
android:fillColor="#D5D5D5"
```

Or check any other attributes, not only color.